# Changing an image's Exif tag "Orientation"

Tags: delphi, gdi+, exif, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to change the [Exif tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) "Orientation" (0x0112) for a given image by code.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41642334/4528159) I've found a working example about reading but I'm failing in writing the same tag.

```
uses
  GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL;

var
  GPImage: TGPImage;
  BufferSize: Cardinal;
  Orientation: Byte;
  RotateType: TRotateFlipType;
  EncoderClsid: TGUID;
  PI : PropertyItem;
begin
  GPImage := TGPImage.Create('.\test_up.jpg');
  try
    BufferSize := GPImage.GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagOrientation);
    if BufferSize <= 0
    then raise Exception.Create('BufferSize <= 0');

    Orientation := 6; //this should be Rotate90FlipNone

    PI.id := PropertyTagOrientation;
    PI.type_ := 3;
    PI.length := BufferSize;
    PI.value := PByte(Orientation);

    GPImage.SetPropertyItem(PI);

    GetEncoderClsid('image/jpeg', EncoderClsid);
    GPImage.Save('.\test_up_Rotate90FlipNone.jpg', EncoderClsid);
  finally
    GPImage.Free
  end;
end;
```

At runtime it raises the following `EAccessViolation` at the `GPImage.SetPropertyItem(PI);` line:

> Access violation at address 757A8E30 in module 'msvcrt.dll'. Read of
> address 00000006.

This is my *test_up.jpg*:

[image: Picture of an arrow pointing up]

Comment: `PByte(Orientation)` is a huge mistake - never mix up type casting with pointers! Another mistake is `PI.length` must be the length of `Orientation`. Did you even notice that `Read of address 00000006` is surprisingly the same as `Orientation := 6;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am successfully using this code:

```
procedure TOvbCustomImage.SetImageOrientation(AGPImage: TGPImage; Value: WORD);
var
    PropItem : TPropertyItem;
begin
    if not Assigned(AGPImage) then
        Exit;
    PropItem.Id            := PropertyTagOrientation;
    PropItem.Length        := SizeOf(WORD);
    PropItem.Type_         := PropertyTagTypeShort;
    PropItem.Value         := @Value;
    AGPImage.SetPropertyItem(PropItem);
end;
```

This is a function I wrote in my application. Full source code at [GitHub](https://github.com/fpiette/OvbImgOrganizer).